# Phonegap not working in device but working in browser

Tags: android, cordova

I am practicing one phonegap application. The functionality working in browser is not working in device. Here I have given the code.

reg.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Daily Word</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="http://debug.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#RegPage").live( 'pageinit' , function (event) {
        $("#btnSignUp").live( 'click', function(){
            var uname=$('.Username').val();
            var pwd=$('.Password').val();
            var email=$('.Email').val();
            alert("check");
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://mysite.in/DailyWord/login.php?Username="+uname+"&Password="+pwd,
                type:"get",
                datatype:"html",
                success: function(response){
                    if( response == "Admin" )
                        {
                            $.mobile.changePage("Admin/admin_home.html",{ transition: "slidedown", changeHash: false  });   
                        }
                    else if( response == "User" )
                        {
                            $.mobile.changePage("User/index.html",{ transition: "slidedown", changeHash: false  }); 
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                }
            });
        });   
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="RegPage">
        <div data-role="header" id="header"><h4>Daily Word</h4></div>
        <div data-role="content">
        <form>
        <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="Username" class="Username" id="text-basic" value="Username" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Username') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Username';">
        <input type="password" name="Password" class="Password" id="text-basic" value="Password" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Password') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Password';">
        <input type="text" name="Email" class="Email" id="text-basic" value="Email" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Email';">
        <input type="button" value="Sign Up" name="btnLogin" id="btnSignUp">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="btnClear">
        </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer" ><h4><a href="http://eazytutor.in/Mobile/">EazyTutor</a></h4></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The same code  working in some other file under same directory but here it is not working. Anyone can help on this?

Alert itself is not working...

Comment: Have you set the INTERNET permission in your AndroidManifest file?

Comment: Yeah... But internet access in some other file under same directory is working...

Comment: I added the script inside the div then started working... Thanks for your support guys...

Comment: Post your last comment as an answer so you can accept your answer and close this post.

Answer (score 0):

I got that working by adding the script in the div page. My correct code as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Daily Word</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="http://debug.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="RegPage">
        <div data-role="header" id="header"><h4>Daily Word</h4></div>
        <div data-role="content">
        <form>
        <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="Username" class="Username" id="text-basic" value="Username" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Username') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Username';">
        <input type="password" name="Password" class="Password" id="text-basic" value="Password" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Password') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Password';">
        <input type="text" name="Email" class="Email" id="text-basic" value="Email" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Email';">
        <input type="button" value="Sign Up" name="btnLogin" id="btnSignUp">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="btnClear">
        </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer" ><h4><a href="http://eazytutor.in/Mobile/">EazyTutor</a></h4></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#RegPage").live( 'pageinit' , function (event) {
        $("#btnSignUp").live( 'click', function(){
            var uname=$('.Username').val();
            var pwd=$('.Password').val();
            var email=$('.Email').val();
            alert("check");
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://mysite.in/DailyWord/login.php?Username="+uname+"&Password="+pwd,
                type:"get",
                datatype:"html",
                success: function(response){
                    if( response == "Admin" )
                        {
                            $.mobile.changePage("Admin/admin_home.html",{ transition: "slidedown", changeHash: false  });   
                        }
                    else if( response == "User" )
                        {
                            $.mobile.changePage("User/index.html",{ transition: "slidedown", changeHash: false  }); 
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                }
            });
        });   
    });
    </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should always put scripts at the bottom of your page. Just inside the body tag will do